# Pandas does not drop nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following group

```
              unemp   nobsRel  measure   rank  nobsRel2  nobsCumSummed
year foo                                                              
2000 8010  0.000024  0.000167      1.0  348.0  0.000167       0.980176
     4950  0.000264  0.003630      1.0  349.0  0.003630       0.983806
     2540  0.000438  0.011027      1.0  350.0  0.011027       0.994833
     9830  0.000118  0.000118      NaN    NaN  0.000118       0.994952
     9920  0.005048  0.005048      NaN    NaN  0.005048       1.000000
```

Here's what happens when I try to drop duplicates:

In[104]: test.drop_duplicates(subset='rank')
Out[104]:

```
              unemp   nobsRel  measure   rank  nobsRel2  nobsCumSummed
year foo                                                              
2000 8010  0.000024  0.000167      1.0  348.0  0.000167       0.980176
     4950  0.000264  0.003630      1.0  349.0  0.003630       0.983806
     2540  0.000438  0.011027      1.0  350.0  0.011027       0.994833
     9830  0.000118  0.000118      NaN    NaN  0.000118       0.994952
```

Why is the last row still there? It is missing!

```
In[105]: np.isnan(test.loc[(2000, 9830), 'rank'])
Out[105]: 
True
```

I'm on `pandas` 0.19.0

Comment: This is default behaviour: `Drop duplicates except for the first occurrence`, so try: `test.drop_duplicates(subset='rank', keep=False)` instead

Comment: I just got back from editing my answer to find this. Why didn't you add it as an answer, then I could have deleted mine (which was, before the edit, incorrect anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `drop_duplicates()`method drops the duplicates except the first one (by default). However, you can choose which one to keep by changing the parameter **keep** setting it to `last`, `first` or `False`. Look at the [documentation here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Try this out :

```
test.drop_duplicates(subset='rank', keep=False)
```

Comment: Nice answer. Gives exactly the information needed, with a helpful link. Keep it up!

Comment: @holdenweb Thanks a lot for your encouragements ! I am trying to be as precise as possible and as synthetic as possible !

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it appears that `drop_duplicates` doesn't do what you want. It removes duplicates, but not the original row that the duplicates are a duplicate of ...

Fortunately that can be overridden with a `keep=False` option to the call.